# How to design a keymap for the macintosh

Tags: keyboard-layout, macintosh, apple

We have a keyboard layout that has been used on Windows since 2004 and since 2007 on Linux systems. The only help that's there for making keyboards for the Mac that we found was here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2056/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003085-CH1-SECTION1

and a way to make a template here:
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90345

Is there a more, may be reliable, way to make an XML keymap for the Mac? I know about Ukelele, but prefer the XML approach because we do not have or can afford Macintosh systems, but some of our users have them.

FYI: We applied to register the Linux one here as bug 90345 at freedesktop org.

Thanks